# Evaluating the integral $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{\ln|z-x|}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration

I don't know how to deal with this integral:

$$\int_{-1}^{1}{\ln\left(\,\left\vert\,z - x\,\right\vert\,\right)\over
                \,\sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}\,1 - x^{2}\,}\,}\,{\rm d}x\,,$$
where $z$ is a complex number.

Comment: @TMM: I think some tags related to complex numbers are needed.

Comment: @BabakS. Certainly you are able to add those tags as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(z)=\int_{-1}^1\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\ln|z-x|~dx$ ,

Then $\dfrac{df(z)}{dz}=\int_{-1}^1\dfrac{1}{(z-x)\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

According to http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int1%2F%28%28z-x%29%281-x%5E2%29%5E%281%2F2%29%29%2Cx%2C-1%2C1,

$\dfrac{df(z)}{dz}=\dfrac{\pi}{\sqrt{z^2-1}}$

$f(z)=\int\dfrac{\pi}{\sqrt{z^2-1}}dz=\ln(z+\sqrt{z^2-1})+C$

But I don't know how to find $C$.

Comment: You forgot a $\pi$ factor before the $\ln\left(z + \sqrt{z^{2} - 1}\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\int_{-1}^{1}{\ln\pars{\verts{z - x}} \over \root{1 - x^{2}}}\,\dd x:
     {\large ?}}$

> From
>   [${\tt \mbox{@paul2357paul answer}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/416445/85343) 
>   it's clear that
>   $\ds{C
>      =\fermi\pars{1}
>      =\int_{-1}^{1}{\ln\pars{\verts{1 - x}} \over \root{1 - x^{2}}}\,\dd x}$. So,
>   we'll evaluate:

\begin{align}
\color{#66f}{\Large C}&
=\int_{-1}^{1}{\ln\pars{\verts{1 - x}} \over \root{1 - x^{2}}}\,\dd x
=\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - x^{2}} \over \root{1 - x^{2}}}\,\dd x
=\lim_{\mu\ \to\ -1/2}\partiald{}{\mu}
\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - x^{2}}^{\mu}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=\lim_{\mu\ \to\ -1/2}\partiald{}{\mu}
\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - x}^{\mu}\,\half\,x^{-1/2}\,\dd x
=\half\,\lim_{\mu\ \to\ -1/2}\partiald{}{\mu}
\int_{0}^{1}x^{-1/2}\pars{1 - x}^{\mu}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=\half\,\lim_{\mu\ \to\ -1/2}\partiald{}{\mu}
\bracks{%
\Gamma\pars{1/2}\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{\mu + 3/2}}
=\color{#66f}{\large -\ln\pars{2}\pi} \approx {\tt -2.1774}
\end{align}

> Then,
>   $$\color{#66f}{\large%
> \int_{-1}^{1}{\ln\pars{\verts{z - x}} \over \root{1 - x^{2}}}\,\dd x
> =\pi\ln\pars{z + \root{z^{2} - 1}} - \ln\pars{2}\pi}
> $$